# Python + FastAPI + OracleCloud: How to expose my python fastapi endpoint on Oracle Cloud to Internet

Tags: python, nginx, gunicorn, fastapi, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have a Python + FastAPI restful API project running the free tier of Oracle Cloud VM instance.

I use Gunicorn to serve the api and also installed Nginx just in case it's needed.

I have tested my running project with

`curl http://localhost:8000`

and I can see my API response.

Now my question is : how can I expose this api endpoint outside on the Internet?

---

**Update 1**

I started my Python API project with this command:

```
gunicorn -w 4 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker main:app --timeout 1200 -b 0.0.0.0
```

I saw the messages below:

```
[2021-05-23 00:40:28 +0000] [3850] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.2
[2021-05-23 00:40:28 +0000] [3850] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (3850)
[2021-05-23 00:40:28 +0000] [3850] [INFO] Using worker: uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker
[2021-05-23 00:40:28 +0000] [3853] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3853
[2021-05-23 00:40:28 +0000] [3854] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3854
[2021-05-23 00:40:28 +0000] [3857] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3857
[2021-05-23 00:40:28 +0000] [3858] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 3858
[2021-05-23 00:42:04 +0000] [3853] [INFO] Started server process [3853]
[2021-05-23 00:42:04 +0000] [3857] [INFO] Started server process [3857]
[2021-05-23 00:42:04 +0000] [3857] [INFO] Waiting for application startup.
[2021-05-23 00:42:04 +0000] [3858] [INFO] Started server process [3858]
[2021-05-23 00:42:04 +0000] [3858] [INFO] Waiting for application startup.
[2021-05-23 00:42:04 +0000] [3858] [INFO] Application startup complete.
[2021-05-23 00:42:04 +0000] [3853] [INFO] Waiting for application startup.
[2021-05-23 00:42:04 +0000] [3853] [INFO] Application startup complete.
[2021-05-23 00:42:04 +0000] [3857] [INFO] Application startup complete.
[2021-05-23 00:42:04 +0000] [3854] [INFO] Started server process [3854]
[2021-05-23 00:42:04 +0000] [3854] [INFO] Waiting for application startup.
[2021-05-23 00:42:04 +0000] [3854] [INFO] Application startup complete.
```

Then I copied the IP address from the Compute >> Instances >> Instance Details panel and accessed it from my Chrome. Straightaway, it shows me

> Unable to connect

Also read through several articles about using Nginx and tried without any luck.

---

**Update 2**

Using `curl` to access the website from my local machine

```
$ curl http://168.138.12.192:8000/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 168.138.12.192 port 8000: No route to host
```

However, when access the IP directly using `curl`, I was able to get the default Nginx website.
$ curl http://168.138.12.192

Comment: did you try to run your application on the `0.0.0.0` ip address?

Comment: hi @BrownBear yes, I have added more details for that in my Update 1. Could you please help?

Comment: try to check via `curl` with you machine ip address

Comment: hi @BrownBear okie, I have updated the details in my Update 2

Comment: I tested from my local machine the command `curl http://168.138.12.192:8000` give me the html code.

Comment: thanks @BrownBear yes, it shows to me as well now. I fixed by running a command. I will update it soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found out what I missed:

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 0.0.0.0/0 --dport 8000 -j ACCEPT
```

I have to run this command to open the port 8000(yes, my website is using port 8000).

I thought I have added Ingress Rule to accept tcp 8000, but it turns out that I still need to run the aforementioned command.

I do not quite understand why I need to do it, but it solves the problem.

Comment: I had the exact same issue and the iptables command  is what got it to work finally. I also could not figure why it is necessary. Would be great if someone could throw some light on it.

Comment: I am also facing the same problem, curl command is not working with public ip. Adding entry in iptables also didn't helped. I checked with Nginx and its accessible outside VM.

Answer (score 0):

Did you changed the default html page under /var/www/html directory? If not try customize the html page as per your requirement and see if it works for you or else it would just show the default nginx page when accessed from browser using public IP.

Adding to this, Also check if the port 8000 is allowed in the security list and OS firewall. The default port for http request is 80, you need to change the default port from 80 to 8000 in the config file to make this work. refer this page this might be useful [How to Change Apache HTTP Port in Linux](https://www.tecmint.com/change-apache-port-in-linux/).